# Mediaplayer went away with unhandled events

Tags: android, button, android-mediaplayer

I make several button sounds, but I can't play all button sounds. I have searched a solution, and the answer seems to be that I need to release() and add reset() before. But when I click the button twice, my app error says "unfortunately, the app has stopped".

My code is this:

```
ImageButton kaa = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.kaa);
    kaa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HurufActivity.this);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.huruf_ka, null);

            ImageButton ka = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ka);
            ka.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    buttonka.start();
                    buttonka.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            buttonka.reset();
                            buttonka.release();
                        }
                    });

                }})
builder.setView(view);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set an OnClickListener inside another OnClickListener.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HurufActivity.this);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.huruf_ka, null);
ImageButton ka = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ka);

buttonka.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if( buttonka != null) {
        if( buttonka.isPlaying()) {
            buttonka.stop();
        }
        buttonka.reset();
        buttonka.release();
        buttonka = null;
        }
    }
});

ka.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        buttonka.start();

    }
});

builder.setView(view);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.show();


ImageButton kaa = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.kaa);
kaa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

           dialog.show();

    }
});
```

Comment: i have button ("kaa") when i click, show alertdialog, inside the alertdialog, i put button named ("ka"), when i click ("ka") there is a sound. and inside alertdialog, i put five button was named ("ka"), ("ki"), ("ku"), ("ke"), ("ko")

Comment: put `dialog.show();` in kaa's OnClickListener (see edit).